# Widgets not updating when I do a setState() In showModalBottomSheet - FLUTTER

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I worked on a flutter program, but I have a problem that I can't solve,
In showModalBottomSheet the widgets do not update when I do a setState();

I've already seen similar problems with the BottomSheet widget, but I need showModalBottomSheet

I would like to point out to you that I have a DraggableScrollableSheet in my showModalBottomSheet and once I close and reopen the widgets are updating but I want the widgets to update instantly

Can you help me resolve it?

Thanks in advance

I tried to do the same principle as BottomSheet but it didn't work

Comment: Can you include sample code that will reproduce the same error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are experiencing an issue with updating widgets inside a `showModalBottomSheet` when using `setState()`.
To resolve this problem, you can try the following fixes:

Firstly, ensure that you are calling `setState()` at the correct location. Make sure it is placed where you want the widget to update, and not outside the `build()` method.

Secondly, check if the widget you want to update is a direct child of the widget wrapped in `setState()`. If it is nested deeper, you might need to pass the updated data down the widget tree using callback functions or state management methods like `Provider` or `Bloc`.

If the widget you want to update is outside the scope of `setState()`, you can use a `GlobalKey` to force the rebuild of that specific widget. Assign a `GlobalKey` to the widget and use `key.currentState.setState(() {})` to trigger a rebuild.

Lastly, ensure that the data you are updating inside `setState()` is being passed correctly to the widget that requires the update. Double-check if the data is being modified as expected.

I have seen a lot used it like below, but i think it is not proper way if you need top rebuild ui directly:

Incorrect

```
 onPressed: () {
    _isBottomSheetVisible = true;
    setState(() {

    });
 },
```

Correct

```
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    _isBottomSheetVisible = true;
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `StatefulBuilder` to wrap the widget you are calling inside the bottom sheet.